# Create an specific index

Tags: sql

Basically i would like to add a new column in a table entitled product (mainly clothes) which contains 2 columns :
- ProductID (int) 
- path (varchar) which is like something |x|y|z| (for example |10|300|5| with 10 indicated that the product is a woman cloth, 300 a t-shirt, and 5 yellow).

So i would like to add a new colum called index in order to allocate in my website a specific place for each products (for example the first picture will be a jean, the second one a coat, the 3rd a t-shirt, etc...). I have 8 zones with the possibility to extend this zone to 8 more, and so on.

I am trying to write an SQL update function such like this :

```
UPDATE productsTable 
SET indexproducts = 
SELECT CASE  path WHEN path LIKE %|1 for example|%  
THEN my index (this index should indicate that the product can be included in the first zone or the 9th zone etc... of my website)
ELSE WHEN path LIKE %|200 for example|%  
THEN my index ( for the second zone) ELSE etc?... 
END 
FROM  productsTable.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: N-o-r-m-a-l-i-z-e your table. There is absloutely no value added by having multiple values stored in one field. Only value - and time and effort - lost. Read about [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example syntax:

```
update  YourTable
set     idx =
        case
        when path like '%least travelled%' then 1
        when path like '%highway%' then 2
        else 3
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your logic on what would be in the indexproducts column, but why not create a computed column:

```
alter table productsTable add indexproducts as 
    case path 
        when '1' then 'include on the first zone'
        when '200' then 'second zone'
        else '...' 
    end
```

then you can create an index on the indexproducts column